# MultipleObjectsReturned at ... get() returned more than one Person -- it returned 2

Tags: django, forms, error-handling

I am using these model:

```
class Person(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    name_in_bangla = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='member_persons')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        unique_together = ['name', 'birth_date']
```

my views:

```
class PersonCreate(SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
    model = Person
    form_class = MemberForm
    success_message = "%(name)s was added as %(category)s successfully."

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.request = self.request
        return form
```

my views:

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude =('user',)

    def clean(self):
        user = get_user(self.request)
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        birth_date = self.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
        if self.instance.id:
            if Person.objects.filter(user=user).exclude(id=self.instance.id).exists():
                self.add_error('name', "You already submitted data")
            elif Person.objects.filter(name=name, birth_date=birth_date).exclude(id=self.instance.id).exists():
                self.add_error('name', "Person with this Name and Birth date already exists.")
        else:
            if Person.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
                self.add_error('name', "You already submitted data")
            elif Person.objects.filter(name=name, birth_date=birth_date).exists():
                self.add_error('name', "Person with this Name and Birth date already exists.")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        person = super().save(commit=False)
        if not person.pk:
            person.user = get_user(self.request)
        if commit:
            person.save()
            self.save_m2m()
        return person
```

It works fine for different persons. But when I try to use same name for person but different birth date it gives MultipleObjectReturn with 'get() returned more than one Person -- it returned 2!'

But I used unique_together = ['name', 'birth_date'] constraints as well as I use clean method to catch the constraints errors in forms. But my forms not catching MultipleObjectReturned errors.

How could I catch these errors in my forms? What my codes doing wrong. Any body suggestions will be appreciated.

MY other views:

```
class PersonDetailView(generic.DetailView):

    queryset = (
         Person.objects.all()
        .prefetch_related('child_set')
         # below omitted because of with tag
        # and conditional display based on time
        # .prefetch_related('blog_posts')
     )
class PersonUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin,UpdateView):

    model = Person
    form_class = MemberForm
    success_message = "%(category)s: %(name)s was updated successfully."

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.request = self.request
        return form


@require_authenticated_permission(
'member.delete_person')
class PersonDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Person
    success_url = '/allmember/'

    success_message = "%(category)s: %(name)s was deleted successfully."


    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
        return super(PersonDelete, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: I get this error when I submitted form and error is shown on the localhost, i.e., http://127.0.0.1:8000/person/ohiduzzaman/

Comment: Then you should show the code for the view that serves that URL, presumably it is some kind of DetailView.

Comment: I posted my DetailView, UpdateView and DeleteView

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two users with the same slug. If your url (which you haven't shown) is `/person/<slug>/`, then you need to set `unique=True` for your slug field.

Comment: My url is: url(r'^person/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', If I use unique=True then could I able to create same name with different birthdate

Comment: Your unique together for `name` and `birth_date` has nothing to do with whether the slug field is unique. If your url is `/person/ohiduzzaman`, but two people have the slug `ohiduzzaman`, then the detail view will simply not work. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: In our case, names are so common. Therefore I want to restrict the same name if their birth dates are same, otherwise I want to allow them to submit their data.

Comment: Sure, I understand that, there's no problem doing `unique_together = ['name', 'birth_date']`. The problem is that your URL `/person/ohiduzzaman/` does not uniquely identify a person, so you cannot use it as a detail view. You either need to make the slug unique, or you need to change your url pattern so that it does uniquely identify the user (e.g. include the primary key or the date of birth).

Comment: Oh!, it gives me logic. Then I can use unique_together = ['slug', 'birth_date'] instead. But problem here user have to type slug on the form, if I exclude slug field in the form and slugify in the model then it gives unique constraints errors. Is there any better way to use slug field without typing it in the form and no unique constraints errors?

Comment: Putting `unique_together = ['slug', 'birth_date']` would only work if you included the birth date and slug in the URL. You would then need to adjust your detail view to fetch the person based on the birth date and slug. Generating a unique slug is a separate question.

Comment: Could you give some examples of using birth date and slug in the URL and adjustment of my DetailView.

Comment: Sorry, I can't write your code for you. You might find the [`DateDetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#datedetailview`) useful.